# HTTP Status 404 - /ShowForm

Tags: java

I am getting HTTP Status 404 - /ShowForm this error pls help me to solve this.

ShowForm.html

```
<form action = "/ShowForm" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" /><br>
File: <input type = "file" name = "file" /><br>
  <input type = "submit" value = "submit" name = "submit">
</form>
```

ShowForm.java

```
@WebServlet("/ShowForm")
public class ShowForm extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public ShowForm() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        ServletInputStream sis = request.getInputStream();
        for(int i = sis.read();i != -1;i = sis.read())
        {
            pw.print((char)i);
        }
    }
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Here I am using Annotation so I have not map in web.xml.

Comment: I guess issue is with with. In controller u are handling as `text/plain` and in Jsp u are sending as `multipart/form-data`

Comment: just change this line <form action = "/ShowForm" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" > to <form action = "ShowForm" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >